# Finding integer roots of an equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

> Find all negative integer solutions of x and y such that
> $$
> x^3 + 3y^2 = xy^2 + 27
> $$

To begin, I isolated $x$ and $y$ to see if there is anything I could do and got
$$
y = \pm \sqrt{x^2+3x+9} \\
x = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(-3 \pm \sqrt{y^2-27}\right)
$$

Since $x$ and $y$ are negative here I thought I could remove the positive branch and got
$$
y = - \sqrt{x^2+3x+9} \\
x = - \dfrac{1}{2} \left(3 + \sqrt{y^2-27}\right)
$$

And I really don't know what to do at this point. I don't have much knowledge on finding integer solutions, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, that's a small mistype I didn't notice. Will fix it

Comment: Those equations are often investigated by applying various moduli. E.g. we get from your equation $x^3-xy^2\equiv x(x^2-y^2)\equiv 0\pmod{3}.$ So $x=3$ is a possibility, and with $x=3$ we get that $y\in \mathbb{Z}$ can be any integer. If $x\neq 3$ then $3\,|\,(x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$ and so on ...

Comment: $3(y^2-9) = x(y^2-x^2)$ looks promising.

Comment: It is evident that $x=3$ and $y$ arbitrary is solution.

Comment: @Piquito Note the problem states it's looking for "*negative* integer solutions", so $x = 3$ is not part of a valid solution.

Comment: @John Omielan: Right. Thanks you sir. (I am 84 years old, and several times I have considered not colaborate with MSE anymore, for obvious reasons). Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation $x^3 + 3y^2 = xy^2 + 27$ can be written as
$$x^3-27+3y^2-xy^2=0$$
$$(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)+y^2(3-x)=0$$
$$(x-3)(x^2+3x+9-y^2)=0$$

Now, $x^2+3x+9-y^2=0$ can be written as
$$\bigg(x+\frac 32\bigg)^2+\frac{27}{4}-y^2=0$$
Multiplying the both sides by $4$ gives
$$(2x+3)^2+27-(2y)^2=0$$
and so
$$(2y-2x-3)(2y+2x+3)=27$$
I think that you can continue from here.